# Обращение от поля объекта к полям нескольких других объектов

Tags: python, django

У меня возник вопрос. Как обратится от start_point и end_point модели Pipeline к 3-м объектам(Factory, OilSump, OilStorage) к полям address?

```
class Factory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = YmapCoord(max_length=200, start_query=u'Россия', size_width=500, size_height=500, unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class OilSump(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = YmapCoord(max_length=200, start_query=u'Россия', size_width=500, size_height=500, unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class OilStorage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = YmapCoord(max_length=200, start_query=u'Россия', size_width=500, size_height=500, unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Pipeline(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start_point = ????
    end_point = ????
```

Comment: Как именно вы хотите обращаться к 3-м объектам? Вызов `start_point` и `end_point` должны ссылаться на те же самые объекты? На все 3 сразу? Добавьте больше конкретики, а еще лучше ваш вариант/попытку решения этого вопроса.

Comment: Получать все названия из трех моделей, а в бд добавляется поле address

Comment: `start_point` должен быть равен трём значениям `address`?

Comment: в админке должны выдавать названия всех объектов из трех моделей, а в бд уже добавлятся address выбранного объекта. Если из поля обращаться посредством ForeignKey, то я это делал с помощью to_field. А именно к 3-м  сразу обратится немогу(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать такой подход:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Pipeline(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    start_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType) # ссылка на модель
    start_id = models.PositiveIntegerField() # id объекта
    start_point = GenericForeignKey('start_type', 'start_id') # ссылка на объект модели

    end_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType) # ссылка на модель
    end_id = models.PositiveIntegerField() # id объекта
    end_point = GenericForeignKey('end_type', 'end_id') # ссылка на объект модели
```

Comment: Немного не то, если использовать это, то нужно еще как-то написать фильтр для ContentType, + выбор идет при написании id в ручную, а не в выборе готовых вариантов, а так же в бд добавляется id, а не address